# Caching with Kotlin Exposed?

Tags: kotlin-exposed

I'm wondering how to add caching when using the Kotlin-Exposed library for SQL access.

For experimentation I've written a small application using both Spring Boot + Hibernate, and KTOR + Exposed.

I did some load-testing and when POSTing to both versions of the application, performance is quite similar with the KTOR + Exposed version having the edge.

However when GETting an existing record from both versions the difference is shocking especially when the database is getting larger - and all time is in Postgres.
My conclusion is that the difference can only be in Hibernate second-level caching that Spring Boot configures.

Seeing the value of caching for items that are repeatedly queried in multiple transactions / sessions, I'm wondering how to configure this in into the low level Exposed framework?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Exposed supports only per-transaction level.

Also, there are `ImmutableCachedEntityClass` which allows you to define some entities (mostly dictionary-like) as cached and share them among application. 
You have to manage cache invalidation manually with `expireCache()` function or actualize entities with `forceUpdateEntity`.

Proper caching in the age of distributed systems is not so easy to implement. You may use any caching library (e.g. [caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine)) and invalidate a cache if you know when your data changes (maybe with help of Exposed `StatementInterceptor`s).

If you'll be able to implement a good caching solution feel free to send PR to the project.